# What free email desktop app is the best for many emails?

Tags: windows, email, email-client

I have many emails to manage, 20+, and it helps greatly if I have an app that encompasses all of them in one inbox, and that's what I have got in my Apple iPhone's default mail app.

However, I want the same experience on my Windows 10 Desktop, most mail apps will **only** give you separate inboxes for each one.

The outlook app doesn't allow this "joint inbox" if I might say. And the Windows Mail App does support it, but then you won't be able to see each mail's inbox separately as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Postbox](https://www.postbox-inc.com/features) a while ago, but ended up not using it.  However, it will do what you want.

Some relevant Features

- **Account Groups**
  Postbox Account Groups lets you organize accounts into groups. Create separate groups to hold your "personal" and "work" accounts, then unify them into one view.
- **Smart Folders**
  A Smart Folder displays email messages that are stored in other folders and that meet certain criteria you specify. For example, a Smart Folder could include all the messages you receive from a specific person, regardless of which folders the messages are stored in.

The licence is only $49, one off.  Disclaimer - I am not associated with it in any way.